# How can I format the output to Manage-bde?

Tags: powershell, encryption

I was recently tasked with keeping track of the laptops that are encrypted with BitLocker.  We have over 300 laptops and not are on the network at the same time.  The person that I took over for was using the flowing command line script to create a txt for each computer.

```
FOR /F %%A IN (c:\Temp\BitLock\BitLock.txt) DO c:\temp\BitLock\PsExec.exe \\%%A -e cmd /c (hostname ^& Date /T ^& manage-bde.exe -status ^& manage-bde -protectors c: -get) >> \\server\Bitlocker\Recovery_Key\2015\%%A.log pause
```

I would like to have that information in one csv so I can quickly go through to see what is not encrypted.  Opening one file at a time seems like a lot of extra work. The below code is what I have come up with in PowerShell.  I am having problems getting the data to show in the cells. I don't think I am using the right object class name.

```
$computers= get-content c:\temp\computerlist.txt  
$txtfile = "c:\temp\test\Computer4.txt"  
foreach ($computer in $computers){
    manage-bde -cn $compute -status | 
        Select "Conversion Status",Password | 
        export-csv c:\temp\test\Computer4.csv
}
```

My end goal is to have it display like below.

Computer Name    Recovery Key   Conversion Status    Protection Status    Computer Description
Name                    XXXXXXXXXX     Fully Encrypted        Protection On       John, Smith Laptop

Comment: You are going to get a string as a return value. Assuming this is the best way to get this information you are going to have to parse it into an object. Do you have an example of the return from a good computer we can use? I don't have bitlocker computers to test with.

Comment: If you have new enough servers and hardware there are PowerShell cmdlets for this as well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj647767.aspx

Comment: I can see a sample from here: http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-manage-bitlocker-from-command-line.html. Would you have multiple volumes encrypted on these laptops? Also I do not see RecoveryKey or ComputerDescription in the return from `-status`

Comment: Even if you does not able to use PowerShell BitLocker cmdlets, proposed by @Matt, you still can use [`Win32_EncryptableVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376483.aspx) WMI class. This WMI class is used internally by `manage-bde.vbs` command, so you should be able to get all the same data in structured form and format them in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but I thought I'd still contribute an answer for anyone else that comes across this.

Here's what I came up with which involved some custom formatting as PowerShell does not see manage-bde output as a PSObject:

```
$computers= get-content c:\temp\computerlist.txt  
$txtfile = "c:\temp\test\Computer4.txt"

$bdeObject = @()
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $bde = manage-bde -cn $computer -status
            $ComputerName = $bde | Select-String "Computer Name:" 
            $ComputerName = ($ComputerName -split ": ")[1]

            $ConversionStatus = $bde | Select-String "Conversion Status:"
            $ConversionStatus = ($ConversionStatus -split ": ")[1]
            $ConversionStatus = $ConversionStatus -replace '\s','' #removes the white space in this field

            $PercentageEncrypted = $bde | Select-String "Percentage Encrypted:"
            $PercentageEncrypted = ($PercentageEncrypted -split ": ")[1]

        #Add all fields to an array that contains custom formatted objects with desired fields
        $bdeObject += New-Object psobject -Property @{'Computer Name'=$ComputerName; 'Conversion Status'=$ConversionStatus; 'Percentage Encrypted'=$PercentageEncrypted;}
    }

$bdeObject | Export-Csv c:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Also I did not see a Recovery Key or Computer Description field in manage-bde. But this gets you a csv with the Computer Name, Conversion Status, and Percentage Encrypted fields.